# Get "real-ip" to backends behind GCP TCP LB

Tags: nginx

At a bit of a loss trying to figure out how a TCP load balancer retains client IP information when passing requests to my backends.

I've found some [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp/setting-up-tcp) that states I need to enable proxy protocol 1 to have the relevant header passed to my backend. I cannot seem to determine how to do this, nothing I've found online show how this should be configured — looking for any docs or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue.

Added option externalTrafficPolicy: Local under Spec section of my deployments LoadBalancer Service config. I can now see the real-ip of clients in my backend logs.